# Android ActionBarActivity and Google Map interacting between tabs

Tags: android, google-maps, tabs, android-actionbar

In my Actionbar activity I got this :

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new FirstActivity();
        case 1:
            return new MapActivity();
        }
    }
```

And I would like to know how I can add a Marker to the google map in the MapActivity Tab from my FirstActivity Tab ?

Would like to access MapActivity setMarker method from FirstActivity but how to achieve this ?

```
public void setMarker(LatLng location, String title) {
    // create marker
    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(
            title);

    // Changing marker icon
    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));

    // adding marker
    googleMap.addMarker(marker);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check following links,it will help you

1)https://github.com/ddewaele/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock/blob/master/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock/docs/part2.md

2)http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seamrecipeId=897&title=MapView%20inside%20TabView

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I looked at the project and actually this helped me : 
https://github.com/ddewaele/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock/blob/master/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock/src/com/ecs/google/maps/v2/simple/SimpleMapFragmentActivity.java

With these lines: 

mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();

Comment: Please add all necessary information to answer the question here and add links only for reference. If the links break, your answer will be useless. For example: the second link is broken already.